# C# send keypress to external program that listens to hotkeys

Tags: c#, winforms, keypress, hotkeys

I have an external program that is running in the background. If I select a number anywhere on my computer, and hit a hotkey (let's say F10), then the external program picks up the number.

Now I'm trying to create a c# winform application that, if the users select text in the application and hit's a button, the external program will pick up this highlighted text (so I actualy simulate an F10 keypress)

This is what I have tried:

```
SendKeys.Send("{F10}");
```

and

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.SelectAll();
    while (true)
    {
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("programname");

        foreach (Process proc in processes)
        {
            SetForegroundWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle);
            SendKeys.SendWait("{F10}");
        }

        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }

}
```

But the external program is not responding to any of the above..
Hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: _"... If I select a number **anywhere** on my computer..."_. What do you mean? BTW **how can your external program see what you selected in your WinForm application**? Your application will go to background and even before that textbox lost focus because of button click...

Comment: I can select numbers in my explorer, word, Firefox etc. and then hit F10. It's a calling program. The moment I hit F10, the program will start calling the number. I want to do the exact same thing with the winform app, but instead hitting F10, I hit a button and send out a simulated F10 press

Comment: If it is truly a *hotkey* then it doesn't matter which window sees the keystroke.  So setting the foreground window doesn't matter.  You'll need to learn more about how this program behaves.

Answer (score 1):

I expect that the program you're talking about registers itself for hotkeys. That means that when you press F10 anywhere, a WM_HOTKEY message would get sent to the hotkey application. When you use SendKeys.Send, you are sending a different windows message, so the hotkey doesn't pickup.

So you'll probably have to PostMessage a WM_HOTKEY with the appropriate values. Just note that the actual key being pressed is not sent in the message - an id passed in RegisterHotKey(of the hotkey application) is in WParam instead, so you have to find out this id somehow. If it's a constant, you can try using Spy++ to figure it out.